# how can i print unicode characters when tailing a log?

Tags: bash, tail

I have log files have things like `\u003c` scattered throughout them.  When I run a command like `tail -f log.txt`, I see escaped unicode characters everywhere, and am wondering what can I do to properly display these characters so I am not seeing escaped stuff?

**EDIT:**

```
>cat log.txt
{:since=\u003e2022-07-20 00:24:47.478898 UTC}
```

```
>hexdump log.txt
0000000 3a7b 6973 636e 3d65 755c 3030 6533 3032
0000010 3232 302d 2d37 3032 3020 3a30 3432 343a
0000020 2e37 3734 3838 3839 5520 4354 0a7d
000002e
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_; [unix.se] is a better fit for questions about usage and behavior of standard UNIX tools.

Comment: ...that said, to answer this anywhere (there included), you'd want to include considerably more detail. Byte-for-byte content of a sample log line (as escaped by `hexdump` or similar); your current `TERM`; output of `locale`; etc.

Comment: If the log contains `\u003c` as six characters (the first of which is a backslash), that's very different from the log containing an actual unicode character (with `tail` transforming it to an escape), and should that be what you're seeing I'd argue that it's something better fixed by adjusting the software _generating_ those logs. But right now the question is simply ambiguous about what your log _actually contains_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have updated my question with the hexdump.

Comment: Consider using the `-C` argument to `hexdump` in the future to make its output easier for humans to consume.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `printf` for translating this kind of escape sequence:

```bash
tail -f log.txt |
while IFS='' read -r line; do printf '%b\n' "$line"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pipe the output of `tail -f` into `hexdump`.

```
tail -f log.txt | hexdump
```